# Scala: Find the DTD declaration in a file

Tags: xml, scala, dtd

I'm not familiar with the scala XML library. Is there a simple way to find the DTD of a document ? From what I've seen so far, `scala.xml.XML.load` only returns the `Elem` (the XML content of the document) but not it's DTD. Is there another method to specifically do that?

Extra question: The same question for the XML declaration at the start of a document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the full document, you'll want to use the [ConstructingParser](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.xml.parsing.ConstructingParser), like so:

```
val cpa = scala.xml.parsing.ConstructingParser.fromSource(src, false)
val doc = cpa.document()
val dtd = doc.dtd
```

The `dtd` is an instance of the [`DTD`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.xml.dtd.DTD) which should provide the information you're looking for.

As for the XML declaration, that's a [`ProcInstr`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/xml/ProcInstr.html). You'll want to look at the `procInstr` callback on the parser for how to get your hands on that.